# Fastboot Device not Detecting my Device

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, windows, bootloader-lock, motorola-moto-g5

I'm following [this](https://www.thecustomdroid.com/unlock-bootloader-on-moto/) tutorial about how to unlock bootloader on Moto.  My device is a Moto G5, and my computer has windows 10.

On the command line, I can type

```
adb devices
```

and it returns my device.  I then do

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

and it turns my phone into bootloader mode.  But when I do

```
fastboot devices
```

it returns a blank line.  According to this source (the second answer), I need to update some the "Unknown 'Android' device".  However, I don't have anything like that.  The closest I have is Other devices->Fastboot potter S.  Do I update this driver?  If so, how?  If I choose "Search automatically for updated driver software," it doesn't find anything.  If I choose "Browse my computer for driver software" and then "Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer", I have to "Select [my] device's type from the list below." but I don't know which one I'm supposed to choose.

How do I fix this problem with fastboot devices?  What drivers am I supposed to update?  How do I fix them?

If this question is better suited on another stackexchange such as superusers on account of it's being more about windows than android, let me know.  I tried asking it there first, but the "android" tag said that the question would be off topic.

Comment: I did enable usb debugging.  I'm not sure about the drivers.  I just installed what the tutorial I linked to recommended in the prerequisites.  I'll try that later to see if it will work.

Comment: USB Debugging is irrelevant within the bootloader. It does its thing within the system and recovery. This might help with the drivers: https://support.motorola.com/in/en/solution/MS89880#

Answer (score 1):

Got stuck at the exact same point when I had this problem! I figured out I could follow the instructions on [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb) (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb), and once I downloaded and installed the right driver, the device showed up when I ran

`fastboot devices -l`

then I just did `fastboot reboot` and everything worked : )